# Write file directly from the request

Tags: node.js

I am having the following logic:

```
 //Defense mechanism code is before the fs operations...

fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) { 
        if (err) {

        } else {
            fs.writeFile(pathLocation, data, function (err) {
                if (err) {                      
                    return res.send(err, 500);
                }
```

As far as I can tell, I am having fs.read and then fs.write... question is can I avoid first fs.read?, in another words read directly from the stream (req.files.image.path)...

I am trying to optimize the code as much as possible.

Comment: what kind of defense mechanisms? there aren't many things that you can do.. check the file extension/min-max filesize/listen for errors thats pretty much what you can do in file uploading.

Comment: There are defense on the client, such as size and type of the file. In my case image. Same check is on the server. By the time I get to the file system operations, I am more or a less confident that stuff in the req is valid image...

Comment: 1st you should never trust the client, check on server side before you start piping the stream to filesystem, there is no special magic into this

Comment: True statement. However, in my scenario this is temp image, that the client is doing a crop. After the crop is done, image is deleted and sent to S3. Point is, when I get to fs... why not avoid one fs?

Comment: Question was not regarding defense, I merely added a comment to show that I have some defense already  in place, so people will not think I am grabbing data directly from the stream :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.files.image` is not a stream. It has already been buffered and written to disk via middleware (presumably the connect `bodyParser`). You can just rename it to it's final FS location via [fs.rename](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback). The `readFile/writeFile` is unnecessary.

You could avoid the write the rename by truly streaming it to disk. Remove the `bodyParser` middleware and directly do: `req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathLocation))` in your route handler.

Note since you mentioned it's an image going to S3, you could actually stream straight from the browser, through your app server without hitting the filesystem, up to S3. This is technically possible, but it's brittle, so most production deployments do use a temporary file on the app server to increase reliability.

You can also upload [straight from the browser to S3](http://blog.tcs.de/post-file-to-s3-using-node/) if you like.

Comment: Good points. I am using app server as a transit point before sending the file to S3 (reducing the file in size and cropping it).

Comment: So it means I can do something like this:   fs.rename(req.files.image.path, pathLocation, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                      
                        return res.send(err, 500);
                    }

Comment: Peter since the req.files.image is already in FS (regardless that is resides in app/temp)... something got me worried now. What stops me from streaming 100GB file??????

Comment: The bodyParser middleware has a "limit" option I think that sets max request body size. This is provided by the connect "limit" middleware, which can also be used on its own.